# My procedure query

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

```
CREATE PROCEDURE driver_report (IN arg_year INT, IN arg_month INT)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
        DECLARE driver_iden INT DEFAULT 0
        DECLARE M_o_w INT DEFAULT 0
        DECLARE C1 CURSOR FOR
            SELECT D_id, MonthR
            FROM driver
            JOIN report USING (D_id)
            WHERE MonthR = arg_month
            AND YearR  = arg_year
            GROUP BY D_id

        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '02000' SET done=1

        OPEN C1 cursor

        WHILE (done = 0) DO
            FETCH C1 INTO driver_iden, M_o_w
            INSERT INTO Report3 ('R3_id', 'Driver_identification', 'Month_of_workD', 'Year_of_workD') 
            VALUES (NULL, d_id, arg_month, arg_year)
        END WHILE

        CLOSE C1 cursor
    END;
```

When i try to execute it, it complains about this done **INT DEFAULT 0** and this **DECLARE driver_iden INT DEFAULT 0**

It says that its the syntax problem, but i'm not sure what exactly may be wrong

**CREATE PROCEDURE driver_report (IN arg_year INT, IN arg_month INT) BEGIN DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0 Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3**

I need to use the cursor in this procedure

Comment: Could you please post the real error message? That will be very helpful.

Comment: `DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;` Is it this one stray semicolon?

Comment: CREATE PROCEDURE driver_report (IN arg_year INT, IN arg_month INT) BEGIN DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0 Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49906887/edit) to include the error message so others can easily see it.

Comment: Every statement must be terminated.

Comment: @P.Salmon you mean add ; to the each row?

Comment: Yes I do and don't forget to set delimiters.https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-programs-defining.html

Comment: @P.Salmon I did add the delimeters and ; after each row but it didnt help at all, the errors are still there

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you could do the job with one query instead of serializing it:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE driver_report (IN arg_year INT, IN arg_month INT)
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO Report3 ('R3_id', 'Driver_identification', 'Month_of_workD', 'Year_of_workD') 
  SELECT DISTINCT driver.D_id, MonthR
  FROM driver
    JOIN report USING (D_id)
  WHERE MonthR = arg_month AND YearR  = arg_year;
END
```

Comment: Unfortunately, i need to use the cursor, its written in my task

Answer (score 0):

You may need to read up the definition of statement. The following at least syntaxes

```
delimiter $$
CREATE PROCEDURE driver_report (IN arg_year INT, IN arg_month INT)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
        DECLARE driver_iden INT DEFAULT 0;
        DECLARE M_o_w INT DEFAULT 0;
        DECLARE C1 CURSOR FOR
            SELECT D_id, MonthR
            FROM driver
            JOIN report USING (D_id)
            WHERE MonthR = arg_month
            AND YearR  = arg_year
            GROUP BY D_id;

        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '02000' SET done=1;

        OPEN C1 ;#cursor the word cursor is not required;

        WHILE (done = 0) DO
            FETCH C1 INTO driver_iden, M_o_w;
            INSERT INTO Report3 (`R3_id`, `Driver_identification`, `Month_of_workD`, `Year_of_workD`) 
            VALUES (NULL, d_id, arg_month, arg_year);
        END WHILE;

        CLOSE C1 ;#cursor the word cursor is not required;
    END $$

    delimiter ;
```

Comment: Did as u wrote and it helped a bit but still i have some issues.       
 Here is my screenshot https://ibb.co/mOd1u7                                                                                                      Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'cursor; WHILE (done = 0) DO FETCH C1 INTO driver_iden, M_o_' at line 16

Comment: The word cursor is not required in the open and close statements, filed names in insert statement should not be delimited by single quotes - either don't use them at all or use backticks. Also I would change the handler declaration to DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR not found SET done=1; And please review https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cursors.html